# Activating Titanium Apple Card: iPhone XS/XR vs iPhone X and earlier

Tags: iphone, apple-card

The process of activating a Titanium Apple Card differ based on model of iPhone.

Specifically, for a 2018 iPhone (iPhone XS/XS Max/XR), one is required to open the Titanium Apple Card packaging, wake the iPhone and hold it near the card. While, for a 2017 or earlier (Apple Card supported) iPhone (iPhone X or earlier), one is required to launch the Wallet app to activate the physical card.

From the Apple Support document, [Request and use your titanium Apple Card](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209434):

> ### How to activate your Apple Card
>
> You need [a compatible iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208531) with [the latest iOS version](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204) to activate your titanium Apple Card. When your titanium Apple Card arrives, it's easy to activate.
>
> [image]
>
> #### Activate on iPhone XS Max, iPhone XS, and iPhone XR
>
> [Watch the video to see how to activate your titanium Apple Card >](https://www.apple.com/apple-card/how-to-videos/#film-activate-card)
>
> 1. Open the packaging that has your titanium Apple Card inside.
> 2. Wake your iPhone and follow the instructions inside your card holder.
> 3. Tap Activate.
>
> #### Activate on iPhone X or earlier
>
> [Watch the video to see how to activate your titanium Apple Card >](https://www.apple.com/apple-card/how-to-videos/#film-activate-card-2)
>
> 1. Open Wallet on your iPhone and tap Apple Card.
> 2. Tap Activate Your Card.
> 3. Wake your iPhone and follow the instructions inside your card holder.
>
> Your card is ready to use as soon as it's activated.

What specifically is the difference in terms of hardware (or software) between 2018 and earlier iPhone models which necessities the difference in activation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone XS/XS Max/XR include a new feature that let them scan NFC tags in the background. For iPhone X and earlier, users must first launch an app to enable NFC reader mode.

- [iPhone Xs and iPhone XR can read NFC tags without having to launch an app](https://9to5mac.com/2018/09/12/iphone-xs-and-iphone-xr-can-read-nfc-tags-without-having-to-launch-an-app/)

> iPhone Xs, iPhone Xs Max and iPhone XR include a new feature for NFC that Apple didn’t mention on stage. The new models will be able to scan NFC tags in the background. With current iPhones, users must first launch an app to enable NFC Reader mode.
>
> iPhone Xs and iPhone XR require no such preamble, the user can simply walk up to a compatible NFC tag, wake the iPhone screen, and scan it …

- [What's New in Core NFC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/702/)

> Background reading of NFC tags is a new feature for iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, and iPhone XR.